# Can mirror and witness have same port number?

Tags: sql-server, configuration, mirroring

When configuring database mirroring, the mirror and the witness have generated the same port number. When I hit next, it errors out with:

> End points for instances for the same server must use different port numbers. Your instances have conflicting port numbers....

Can they have the same port number?

Answer (score 3):

As detailed in [this MSDN document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179511.aspx#Anchor_0), the port number must be unique *within any given computer*:

> Note that if more than one server instance on a given computer requires a database mirroring endpoint, specify a different port number for each endpoint.

TCP ports can only be *served* by a single process.  When you try to create two endpoints with the same port number *on the same computer*, you are attempting to have two processes monitor the *same* port.

This image is contained on that page, and makes it quite clear:

[image]

If you are using unique computers for all machines in the mirroring configuration, you can configure each computer with the *same* port.